# Hello, i want to close modal button... but i close

Tags: jquery, dialog, widget, modal-dialog, jqgrid

```
buttons: [

    {
        text: "Yes",
        "class": 'btn btn-danger',
        click: function() {
            tbl_dl_user_mstDelID = gsr[0];
            $.post( "php/tbl_dl_user_mst.php?cmd=resetPassword&id="+tbl_dl_user_mstDelID, function(data){
                
                if(data.result=="true"){
                    $("#tbl_dl_user_mstdialog-confirm").dialog("close");

                    $("#alert_dialog").html(data.msg);
                    $("#alert_dialog").dialog("open");
                    $("#ttbl_dl_user_mst_ds_list").trigger( "reloadGrid" );
                }else{
                    $("#tbl_dl_user_mstdialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                    $("#alert_dialog").html(data.error);
                    $("#alert_dialog").dialog("open");
                }
            },"JSON");
        }
    },
    {
        text: "No",
        "class": "btn btn-success",
        click: function() {
            $("#tbl_dl_user_mstdialog-confirm").dialog("close");
        }
    }
```

I want to close modal button. tbl_dl_user_mstdialog-confirm is a dialogue box...